# Flutter Firebase Check Which Collections Have Same Doc

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello to be more spesific I have an collection "Sellers" and it contains my sellers "SellerA,SellerB..." as documents.Each one of those documents contain another collection named "Products" and it contains a set of items as docs.So I need to check which sellers have ProductA.
For an example Sellers/SellerA/Products/ProductA.I will have 1000+ sellers so I cant check them all one by one.

I tried:

```
Future<List<String>> getCollectionsWithDocA() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Sellers')

        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: 'ProductA')
        .get();

    List<String> collectionsWithDocA = [];
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.docs) {
      print(doc.reference.parent.parent!.id);


      collectionsWithDocA.add(doc.reference.parent.parent!.id);
    }

    return collectionsWithDocA;
  }
```

and it does not work. Result is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. When querying a collection group by FieldPath.documentId(), the value provided must result in a valid document path, but 'ProductA' is not because it has an odd number of segments (1).

Also ChatGPT suggested this:

```
void getCollections()async{
    String documentName = 'ProductA';

    List<String> collectionsWithDocA = [];

    QuerySnapshot allCollections = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("Sellers").get();

    for (CollectionReference collectionRef in allCollections.docs) {
      QuerySnapshot docs = await collectionRef
          .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: documentName)
          .get();
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        collectionsWithDocA.add(collectionRef.id);
      }
    }

    if (collectionsWithDocA.isNotEmpty) {
      print('The following collections have a document named $documentName:');
      print(collectionsWithDocA);
    } else {
      print('No collections have a document named $documentName.');
    }
  }
```

This code gives this error on allCollections.docs :

> The type 'List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable' with a type argument that can be assigned to 'CollectionReference<Object?>'.

What can I try next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a collection group index, the `documentId` holds the path to the document (as that is required to make the entries in the index unique). So the value `ProductA`  is not a valid value for `documentId` in a collection group index, and query.

What you essentially want is a `endsWith` type clause, but Firestore doesn't support those.

The only solution I can think of is to duplicate the `ProductA` value into each relevant document as a regular field, and then query on that field in your collection group query.

Comment: Yeah I found same method too. I will use it. Thanks !